# Validar reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, html, captcha

Buen dia a todos, despues de revisar un montón de preguntas en stack he decidido realizar una pregunta para ver si me pueden ayudar!

Este es mi archivo **index.html** Mas o menos

---

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="box">
      <form method="post" action="guardar.php">

        <div class="field half first"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required pattern="[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.'-]{2,48}" /></div>

        <div class="field half"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo"required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" maxlength="155" /></div>

        <div class="field"><textarea name="message" placeholder="Mensaje" rows="6" required maxlength="500"></textarea></div>

          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div>

        <ul class="actions">
          <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar Clasificado"/></li>
        </ul>
      </form>

    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

He visto varios tutoriales ya y no he podido lograrlo. Es que si el usuario no hace click en el captcha y presiona el botón enviar clasificado no pueda enviarlo y le salga una validación que diga que debe validar el captcha.

¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Comment: Te falta obtener tu `data-sitekey` desde este sitio https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin y después implementar la validación del lado del servidor

Comment: Si perdon yo puse las xxxx solo aqui, las tengo en mi index perfectamente todo. Lo que no se como hacer esa validacion!